# How do HTTP servers handle very large HTTP requests?

Tags: http, tomcat, jetty

As I understand, the body size of HTTP POST request is unlimited. Thus a client may send *gigabytes* of data in one HTTP request. Now I wonder how an HTTP server should handle such requests. How do `Tomcat` and `Jetty` handle them ?

Answer (score 2):

Not true. For example Apache has a default size of 20 MB, configurable in httpd.conf. Then  TCP connection will be closed so client cannot send anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat is configured to limit the post size to 2 MB by default. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html:

> maxPostSize
>
> The maximum size in bytes of the POST which will be handled by the container FORM URL parameter parsing. The limit can be disabled by setting this attribute to a value less than or equal to 0. If not specified, this attribute is set to 2097152 (2 megabytes).